# How can I update records returned by subquery in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I want to update a single record that is returned by a subquery which looks like below
[image: Inner query result]

The query I have written to update is

```
update aa_dev.calls set cid = 1000 from (
select * from (
SELECT 
    *,
    CASE WHEN cid IS NULL THEN
       row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY cid IS NULL)
    ELSE 0 end as rownum
FROM
    aa_dev.calls) t2 
   where rownum = 2) t3;
```

The problem is this query updates all the Records to 1000 and not just the record that is returned from the subquery.

So I want to update only the row that is returned from the subquery. How can I alter this query so that it doesn't update all the records.

Comment: Best way would be using an identifier. Do you have an id column or something?

Comment: You need some kind of "join" between the subquery and the UPDATE part e.g. `where t3.id = calls.id`

Comment: @S-Man No, I just have row_number() column and cid

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: He meant the same thing like me: You need a column which can be used for joining. I you had an id column, you could do something like: `UPDATE table t SET column = s.new_value FROM (SELECT id, new_value FROM table) s WHERE s.id = t.id` To do this, you need to identify the correct record using a specific criterion like an id column

Comment: @Chloe `row_number()` is not a table column, it's dynamically created during a query only. So your `calls` table really has only a single column, `cid`? Then you cannot even distinguish those where `cid IS NULL`, they're all the same record, and you may just update all of them at once.